# Docker hosted redis losing data

Tags: docker, redis, persistent

I am running standalone Redis using `docker-hub` image with volume 
for
`persistent storage(--appendonly yes)`, however after a while all the keys from the Redis are disappearing.
I haven't set the `EXPIRE` time for any of the keys.
Runnning the docker with following command :

```
docker run  -p 6379:6379 -v redis-vol:/data -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes
```

Can anyone please let me know what might be going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Could it be that your dockerized Redis server is accessible to the outside world (without a password)? If so, someone is probably running FLUSHALL when trying to p0wn your server.

Comment: Yup. someone was running FLUSHALL. After setting the password it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you will be losing the keys each time you are creating a new container, although you have a permanent storage 'volume'.
The thing you are missing is to set the environment variables `ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes` and `DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL,CONFIG`
If you are using `docker-compose` file you can simply add them as:

```
redis:
image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
environment:
  - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  - DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL,CONFIG
container_name: haproxy_redis_auth_redis
ports:
  - "6379:6379"
volumes:
  - redis-data:/bitnami/redis/data
```

In so case, do not forget to make your application depends on `redis` service

```
application:
build: .
depends_on:
  - db
  - redis
```

I had the same issue which been fixed after I took a look here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/redis/